# dijkstra algorithm for big graphs

Tags: python, graph, dijkstra

I am implementing Dijkstra's algorithm using standard Python libraries.

my implementation below is ok for test cases with little graphs.
When I run it on a big one (more than 30k nodes), it is not great.

Wonder if anybody can help improving it.

I do not understand if the stop checks are not correct of if there is something else missing

```
import logging
from collections import deque, namedtuple

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# use infinity as a default distance to nodes.
inf = float("inf")
Edge = namedtuple("Edge", "start, end, cost")


def make_edge(start, end, cost=1):
    return Edge(start, end, cost)


class Graph:
    def __init__(self, edges):
        # check that the data is right
        wrong_edges = [i for i in edges if len(i) not in [2, 3]]
        if wrong_edges:
            raise ValueError("Wrong edges data: {}".format(wrong_edges))

        self.edges = [make_edge(*edge) for edge in edges]

    @property
    def vertices(self):
        return set(sum(([edge.start, edge.end] for edge in self.edges), []))

    def get_node_pairs(self, n1, n2, both_ends=True):
        if both_ends:
            node_pairs = [[n1, n2], [n2, n1]]
        else:
            node_pairs = [[n1, n2]]
        return node_pairs

    def remove_edge(self, n1, n2, both_ends=True):
        node_pairs = self.get_node_pairs(n1, n2, both_ends)
        edges = self.edges[:]
        for edge in edges:
            if [edge.start, edge.end] in node_pairs:
                self.edges.remove(edge)

    def add_edge(self, n1, n2, cost=1, both_ends=True):
        node_pairs = self.get_node_pairs(n1, n2, both_ends)
        for edge in self.edges:
            if [edge.start, edge.end] in node_pairs:
                return ValueError("Edge {} {} already exists".format(n1, n2))

        self.edges.append(Edge(start=n1, end=n2, cost=cost))
        if both_ends:
            self.edges.append(Edge(start=n2, end=n1, cost=cost))

    # @property
    # def neighbours(self):
    #     neighbours = {vertex: set() for vertex in self.vertices}
    #     for edge in self.edges:
    #         neighbours[edge.start].add((edge.end, edge.cost))

    #     return neighbours

    # use the following if the graph is undirected / bidirectional
    @property
    def neighbours(self):
        neighbours = {vertex: set() for vertex in self.vertices}
        for edge in self.edges:
            neighbours[edge.start].add((edge.end, edge.cost))
            neighbours[edge.end].add((edge.start, edge.cost))

        return neighbours

    def dijkstra(self, source, dest):
        assert source in self.vertices, "Such source node doesn't exist"
        distances = {vertex: inf for vertex in self.vertices}
        previous_vertices = {vertex: None for vertex in self.vertices}
        distances[source] = 0
        vertices = self.vertices.copy()

        while vertices:
            current_vertex = min(vertices, key=lambda vertex: distances[vertex])
            vertices.remove(current_vertex)
            if distances[current_vertex] == inf:
                break
            for neighbour, cost in self.neighbours[current_vertex]:
                alternative_route = distances[current_vertex] + cost
                if alternative_route < distances[neighbour]:
                    distances[neighbour] = alternative_route
                    previous_vertices[neighbour] = current_vertex
                    logger.debug("updating Graph distances", format(distances))

        path, current_vertex = deque(), dest
        while previous_vertices[current_vertex] is not None:
            path.appendleft(current_vertex)
            current_vertex = previous_vertices[current_vertex]
        if path:
            path.appendleft(current_vertex)
        logger.debug("path to destination is \n")

        while path:
            value = path.popleft()
            logger.debug("{} \n".format(value))

        return distances[dest]
```

and this is the test case:

```
graph = Graph(
    [
        ("a", "b", 7),
        ("a", "c", 9),
        ("a", "f", 14),
        ("b", "c", 10),
        ("b", "d", 15),
        ("c", "d", 11),
        ("c", "f", 2),
        ("d", "e", 6),
        ("e", "f", 9),
    ]
)


result = graph.dijkstra("a", "e")
print(result)
assert result == 20
```

Comment: How about trying [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.dijkstra_path.html) instead of rolling your own? When you say "it is not great", what specifically is not great? Too slow? Errors?

Comment: Or, if you insist on creating your own algorithm, consider using the heap data structure to save time finding the minimal node you will search on

Comment: This is a question for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "it is not great."  What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Takes ages to find a solution.

Comment: Anyways I did find a way to use minheap and speed up. But is only for directed edges. For bidirectional graph I am still working on it